Google OAuth pop-up disappears
I have developed a web auth application using Google OAuth. it was okay when i was developing it. but after hosting it when click on the continue with google button the google sign in pop up appears and suddenly disappears.
this is the link of the web app :
https://mern-auth-58x5.onrender.com/sign-in
can anyone please find a solution for this ?
It was okay when I was developing it. when i click on the continue with google button, it signed in and navigated to the home page. but after deploying it in the render it is not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I tested Google Sign-in with your code and checked the developer console and it shows auth/unauthorized-domain error. This means that you are using Firebase AuthProvider for Google Sign-in, but you have not added your website domain to the list of Authorized domains in your Firebase Authentication settings.

To resolve the error, you need to register your website domain in your Firebase Authentication settings. I'll provide images to help you find the solution easily.


Log in to the Firebase console
Click the Authentication tab in the left bar
Go to Settings/Authorized Domains
Click Add Domain
Add your website domin and save the changes.It will solve your current issue.

